# pass shared_ptr as a argument to a function which accepts object of a class type

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am wondering , is it possible to pass shared_ptr as a argument to a function which accepts pointer of class type

Example

```
class class_A_type
{
 bla bl a

 private:
    IStuff *mStuff;
}

class IStuff
{
  public:
    IReporter(){};
    virtual ~IReporter(){};
    virtual void ReportResults( class_A_RESULT_TYPE *pResult) = 0;
};

void class_A_type::SendResultBack( bool status, std::string statusString )
{
        boost::shared_ptr< class_A_RESULT_TYPE >aResultBptr( new class_A_RESULT_TYPE ( mStuff, GetPropertyName() ) );
        bool lbool = false;
        std::string lstr = "running";
        aResultBptr->setStatus( lbool, lstr );
        myStuff->ReportResults( aResultBptr );// ERROR  HOw to pass shared _ptr ?? 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `get` function on `shared_ptr`.

```
myStuff->ReportResults( aResultBptr.get() );
```